Remove <!-- wp:paragraph --> in WordPress
I decided to delete the codes inside  to make the page load faster, but I didn't find a function for it.
I mean these codes:
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>test</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph --> 

At first, I wanted to delete the letters according to the number of letters in this comment tag, but this is futile because by changing the type of text layout, their number changes.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

For what it’s worth, these are HTML comments. You can delete them by loading your page into a php DOMDocument object, then using other parts of that subsystem to remove comment tags.
They serve a purpose, though. They tell the block editor where blocks begin and end.
And, WordPress sites with speed problems often have tens of thousands of extra bytes being downloaded, in poorly compressed images or extra .js files or whatever. Removing these HTML comment takes will save tens of bytes, and so may not be helpful enough to be worth the trouble.

Unfortunately, this is not the case, their number is very large, so that sometimes their number reaches a third of all the codes on the page!!
